# Storing a sqllite database in a location that visual studio and dotnet can see it

Tags: c#, sqlite, asp.net-core, .net-core

So I have a solution with two projects (webapi, console app) in it.  I created a shared directory between them to put a sqlite database.

So I use

```
     Path.GetFullPath(@"../shared/" + Configuration["DBName"]);
```

and get this path when i run it in visual studio 2017

```
     \shared\sqlite.db
```

However when I try to run the console command

```
     dotnet ef database update
```

it thinks it's located here

```
     \projecta\bin\Debug\shared\
```

How can I get the Visual Studio debug and dotnet ef commands to use the same path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `Path.GetFullPath`, it uses the value of `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory`, which may vary based on who called your code (VS, dotnet, etc)

A better way to do this is give your SQLite file path a consistent location that won't vary based on the caller:

```
var dbPath = Path.Combine(System.AppContext.BaseDirectory, "..", "shared", Configuration["DBName"]);
```